# Is This Moderation Style New? If So I Like It

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-tools

I just noticed the warning box in the following question:

[Is there a canonical book on functional design specifications?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115654/is-there-a-canonical-book-on-functional-design-specifications)

I think it is very helpful. Is this new? Who can moderate questions like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a new ["post notices" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners/107142#107142) that was introduced last month.

Currently there are three options:

> 1. This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.
> 2. Post is related to a rapidly changing event
> 3. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommend it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for more information.

Only moderators can add these notices, so feel free to flag questions you think could use them.

Comment: #3 says: `why *you're recommended* it`

Comment: @Mike Oh hey, so it does. Thanks. :) I [reported it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110107/typo-in-the-honeypot-question-post-notice-text) on Meta Stack Overflow, so it should get fixed up by a developer.